# Encountered two children with the same key, `` in React_Native

Tags: react-native

I have a problem with keys, but i dont know why.
`I get this error Warning: Encountered two children with the same key,. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.     in AndroidHorizontalScrollContentView (created by ScrollView)     in AndroidHorizontalScrollView (created by ScrollView)     in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)     in ScrollView (created by VirtualizedList)     in VirtualizedListContextProvider (created by VirtualizedList)     in VirtualizedList (created by FlatList)     in FlatList (created by TourCard)     in RCTView (created by View)     in View (created by TourCard)     in TourCard (created by Dashboard)`

But i give the elements already keys if im right:

I Create a FlatList with this:
   `<FlatList       data={imageReferences}       keyExtractor={(item) => item}       renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderItem({ item, index })}       horizontal={true}       showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}     />`
and inside this function

`const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {       if (item != "") {         return (           <View style={styles.item} key={`view-${index}`}>             <Image source={{ uri: item }} style={styles.image} key={`image-${index}`} />           </View>         );       }     };`

i create this Images, they get keys like you can see but still i have empty keys which are also atleast double the time there.
What is wrong with my code? Im Clueless, any help is appriciated.

Greetings

Philipp

Comment: Please add line breaks to your code. Right now it's nearly unreadable. Code blocks can be added with three backtick characters. (```)

Comment: Thanks for the help, i will do it as soon as i find the time. Approximately in a week. So for the future the people can read my code better. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change `keyExtractor={(item) => item}`  to `keyExtractor={(item, index) => 'key'+index}`

Answer (score 0):

change keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}